# Angular 10 - Waiting for Service to Return Information Before Rendering

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, wait

I'm attempting to implement FusionAuth authentication to a site and have been running into a significant issue with Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox. Right now, depending on the body of the response, it will either automatically redirect you to the FusionAuth login page, or will direct you to the site homepage, which is contained in the navbar.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="this.loggedIn == false; then thenTemplate; else elseTemplate"></ng-container>
<ng-template #thenTemplate>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=login_url">
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</ng-template>
```

This is the service to gather user information. In the component that the check is done in, it checks if the information contains an email address or not, since an email is required for all users. If there's an email, it sets the "loggedIn" property to true, otherwise it's false.

```js
export class UserService {

  private SERVER_URL = "serverURL";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = 'Unknown error!';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    window.alert(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }

  public get() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.SERVER_URL, {withCredentials: true}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
}
```

And finally, here is the check. The issue is occurring here, I believe:

```js
  user: any;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(private userService: UserService){}

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.userService.get().subscribe((data: any) => {
      if(data.email != null){
        this.loggedIn = true;
      }
      else{
        this.loggedIn = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

At this point, Firefox somehow is able to wait for the async request, but Chrome is sending the user through an infinite login redirect.

Basically my question is, how can I force Angular to wait to process the Service request and continue forth until all the information has been received? I've attempted turning the response into a promise and returning that way, but with no luck.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm not experienced with this myself, but I think you're asking for [Resolve functionality](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: `httpclient` operations are obervables, meaning that by default nothing happens until the it is subscribed and the request returns and success or error. where is the code that does the actual redirect? looking at the sample code you provided, your `catcherror` handler opens an alert, but I don't see the redirect.  do you have an Interceptor that you are using, that isn't copied here by any chance?

Comment: This might help https://dev.to/jwp/observable-to-promise-for-async-await-2d9c

Comment: @Edward the redirect is happening within the IfThenElse statement in the first code entry, the meta tag redirects IF loggedIn == false. I wonder if there's a better way to set up the logic in the component itself to set tags, if you have any suggestions feel free to let me know.

Comment: I didn't see that this was being done in the template. I was expecting to see it in the Class. I tried to reproduce the issue with just the template and created the stackblitz here -> [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-71zjt1?file=src/app/app.component.html) but it's working as expected there. this leads me to ask if there is no other place where `loggedIn` might be getting set to false. An alternative would to handle the redirect in the class via `window.location.href=` or `window.location.replace`